# How to create OutPutContext via V2 client library for node js

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on entity and intents creation in my agent using v2 client library for node.js . And for that i am going through this [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js) which is on git. And it says something related to session id and context id. Can anyone explain me what is sessionId and contextId. And also provide me link where i can read those thing in details.

I am unable to create context by following those example. How can i create context while creating intent at the same time.

Comment: what's the code you are using currently for creating the intent? please provide the exact code, i was able to provide context as well, need to see your code to suggest modifications.

Comment: for creating the intent you will be calling createIntent() method only which you have provided in the link. anyway, you can see this for reference: https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/62 its in python but you can easily convert it into node js

Comment: you basically need to add one line.

Answer (score 1):

The following is code to create a context.  You cannot create a context and an intent in a single API call, you first need to create the context and then create the intent that uses the context.  The response to the create context API call will return a context ID you can use in your intent.

```
  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

  // Instantiates clients
  const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient();

  // The path to the agent the created entity type belongs to.
  const agentPath = entityTypesClient.projectAgentPath(projectId);

  const createEntityTypeRequest = {
    parent: agentPath,
    entityType: {
      displayName: displayName,
      kind: kind,
    },
  };

  entityTypesClient
    .createEntityType(createEntityTypeRequest)
    .then(responses => {
      console.log(`Created ${responses[0].name} entity type`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to create size entity type:', err);
    });
```

Source: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js

Comment: above code which you have given in your answer is related entity creation. I am confused. how this can help me in context creation.

Comment: As you said that **You cannot create a context and an intent in a single API call, you first need to create the context and then create the intent**. I didn't find such thing mentioned anywhere in docs. Can you please share some links where i can read those thing in details

Comment: Its not in the docs explicitly, but is a fact of how you create intents and contexts via the API.  If you create an intent and wish to have a context attached to it you need to refer to the context by ID.  A context ID is created for a context when it is created by Dialogflow and cannot be known before the context is created.  Thus since a intent requires a context ID and and context ID is not generated until the context is created a context must be created before an intent is created.

Comment: Can you replace code in your answer with code related to context. Code which you have provided is for entity

Comment: @FaisalAhmed here you have some context functions to insert in your code: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/762cb8f5ba3b83067ac1a781f004aed1219f1e74/samples/resource.js#L354

Comment: it is just *output contexts* that need this complicated session based context? For 'input contexts' surely just the name of a context would do? ie a simple string. But of course it will probably be a complicated thing related to the project ID, but not like the code linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Contexts are very closely associated with SessionID. Say for eg, you have a chatbot that gets spun up on two computers serving two different user's. Each user will have a respective session_id (If you're coding in NODE, when a new user fires the chatbot, you need to ensure he/she will get a unique session_id).

Now, every unique session id will have unique contexts. From above example, let's say user 1 will initialize an intent that has input context named 'abc' with lifespan of 2 and user 2 will initialize another intent that has input context named 'xyz' with lifespan of 5, these respective contexts gets recorded against each of these user's individual session id's. You can programatically control (edit) contexts and its lifecycle. This is the biggest advantage of code facilitated Dialogflow as opposed to using GUI. Using services like Firebase, you can also preserve session id's and its associated contexts so, next time same user sign's in again, they can start from where they had last left.

I can share a snippet from one of my previous projects where I was managing contexts programatically. Initialization script is as follows:

```
/**
 * @author Pruthvi Kumar
 * @email pruthvikumar.123@gmail.com
 * @create date 2018-08-15 04:42:22
 * @modify date 2018-08-15 04:42:22
 * @desc Dialogflow config for chatbot.
 */

const dialogflow_config = {
    projectId: 'xxx',
    sessionId: 'chatbot-session-id', //This is default assignment. This will hve to be overridden by sessionId as obtained from client in order to main context per sessionId.
    languageCode: 'en-US'
};

exports.configStoreSingleton = (function () {
    let instanceStacks;
    let instanceSessionId;

    let contextStack = {};
    let intentsStack = {};
    let successfulIntentResponseStack = {};

    function init() {
        contextStack[dialogflow_config['sessionId']] = [];
        intentsStack[dialogflow_config['sessionId']] = [];
        successfulIntentResponseStack[dialogflow_config['sessionId']] = [];

        return {
            contextStack: contextStack,
            intentsStack: intentsStack,
            successfulIntentResponseStack: successfulIntentResponseStack
        };
    }

    return {
        init: function () {
            if (!instanceStacks || (instanceSessionId !== dialogflow_config['sessionId'] && (!intentsStack[dialogflow_config['sessionId']]))) {
                console.log('[dialogflow_config]: Singleton is not instantiated previously or New userSession is triggered! Fresh instance stack will be provisioned');
                instanceStacks = init();
                instanceSessionId = dialogflow_config['sessionId'];
            }
            return instanceStacks;
        }
    };
})();

exports.updateSessionIdOfDialogflowConfig = function (sessionId) {
    if (typeof (sessionId) === 'string') {
        dialogflow_config['sessionId'] = sessionId;
        return true;
    } else {
        console.warn('[dialogflow_config]: SessionId must be of type STRING!');
        return;
    }
};

exports.getDialogflowConfig = function () {
    return dialogflow_config;
};
```

And then, to programmatically manage contexts:

```
/**
 * @author Pruthvi Kumar
 * @email pruthvikumar.123@gmail.com
 * @create date 2018-08-15 04:37:15
 * @modify date 2018-08-15 04:37:15
 * @desc Operate on Dialogflow Contexts
 */

const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const dialogflowConfig = require('../modules/dialogflow_config');
const structjson = require('./dialogflow_structjson');
const util = require('util');

const contextsClient = new dialogflow.ContextsClient();

exports.setContextHistory = function (sessionId, intent_name, context_payload, preservedContext=false) {
  /* maintain context stack per session */
  /* context_payload = {input_contexts: [], output_contexts = []}
   */
  const contextStack = dialogflowConfig.configStoreSingleton.init().contextStack;

  if (intent_name) {
    contextStack[sessionId].push({
      intent: intent_name,
      contexts: context_payload,
      preserveContext: preservedContext
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('[dialogflow_contexts]: Intent name is not provided OR Nothing in context_payload to add to history!');
  }

};

exports.getContextHistory = function () {
  const contextStack = dialogflowConfig.configStoreSingleton.init().contextStack;
  return contextStack;
}

exports.preserveContext = function () {
  const contextStack = dialogflowConfig.configStoreSingleton.init().contextStack;
  //Traverse contextStack, get the last contexts.
  let context_to_be_preserved = contextStack[dialogflowConfig.getDialogflowConfig()['sessionId']][contextStack[dialogflowConfig.getDialogflowConfig()['sessionId']].length - 1];
  //console.log(`context to be preserved is: ${util.inspect(context_to_be_preserved)}`);
  return context_to_be_preserved['contexts'].map((context, index) => {
    let context_id = exports.getContextId(context);
    return exports.updateContext(context_id, true)
  });
}
```

From here, you can reference this github resource to build your own contexts - https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js

Happy creating digital souls!

Comment: it is just output contexts that need this complicated session based context? For 'input contexts' surely just the name of a context would do? ie a simple string. This is how it's managed in the DialogFlow UI, there is no session/user dependent thing to the context.